# Image being cropped when max-width is active

Tags: css, wordpress, height, width, crop

The footer of [this WP site](https://domingodasorte.com.br/contato/) has 3 logo images:
The image's original dimensions are very different, so I want to restrict its `max-width` and `max-height`, which I put in the `wp-image-490` class:

[image]

But when I do this, after reducing the window size, the image is being cropped:

[image]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try update your css with below code

CSS

```
.wp-image-490 {
    width: 100%;    /* Newly added */
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

Comment: This deforms the second image when you increase the screen size... have you already tested?

Comment: Thanks, but I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

See if you can add a different class (or id) for your first logo, that your second and third logo don't have.

Then for this class (or id), add the rule

```
<your class/id> {
    width: 100%;
}
```

(As [Par Thea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5079499/par-tha) suggested above)

Comment: Those logos are from a user-generated table, so I have no control from each element, thus, it's not possible to have specific classes for specific images. There has to be just one generic class for ao logo images.

Comment: Are there any classes higher up that you could edit? For example in the .Rtable-cell elements? In that case, you could still use a different rule for the logo below that class.

Comment: If not, one final solution that I can think of is that you use: img[src="https://domingodasorte.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/Caçanjure-FM-PNG.png"] {
    width: 100%;
} This really isn't pretty, though, and only works if you are sure the src url for the logo does not change.

Comment: Thanks, but I found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem mentioned inserting the following elements on the class:

```
.wp-image-490 {
    object-fit: contain; /* fix the image distortion caused by "width: 100%" */
    width: 100%; /* fix the image cropping caused by "max-width" */
    max-height: 200px;
    max-width: 350px;
}
```